# Глобальная переменная недоступна во всех методах

Tags: python

Получаю строки из гугл-таблицы. В режиме отладки в методе `updateDataInSheet` я вижу что данные есть, а во втором методе они пустые. Хоть убей не пойму в чем причина.

```
  recs = list()

    def updateDataInSheet():

        client = gspread.authorize(creds)
        sheet = client.open("#xxx").sheet1

        recs = sheet.get_all_values()
        threading.Timer(600.0, updateDataInSheet).start() # called every minute
        print("data updated")
    def searchByEF(stroka):
        info = {}
        content = []

        stroka = stroka.split()
        try:
            for rec in recs: #recs пустая
```

Comment: Если несложно скиньте код с где вы обращаетесь к updateDataInSheet, searchByEF. Но скорее всего в searchByEF вы передаёте пустое значение, и из updateDataInSheet вы ничего не возвращаете добавьте return recs, recs - это ж значения ячеек?

Comment: global recs перед строкой с присваиванием. Unrelated: использования глобальных переменных в таком контексте стоит избегать

Comment: @JackWolf добавил return recs в updateDatainSheet. Все робит. Однако, как мне его в таймере добавить?

Comment: Уберите threading.Timer из функции, вставьте её в __main__ и будет вам счастье, update = threading.Timer(600.0, updateDataInSheet) update.start()

Comment: @JackWolf у меня просто еще и bot

Comment: @JackWolf   def main(argv=None):
    recs = threading.Timer(600.0, updateDataInSheet)
    recs.start()
    bot.polling()          вот так?

Comment: @JackWolf не, так оно не пашет

Comment: Не совсем, есть функция, которая срабатывает после запроса пользователя, то уже через эту функцию вы можете обращаться к updateDatainSheet. Т.е user <-> функция <-> updateDatainSheet